# python select lines based on maximum value of a column

Tags: python, list

I'm not very familiar with Python, but there's something I need to do. I have an ASCII file (space-separated) of several columns. In the first column, some values are duplicates. From these duplicate values, I need to select the lines which have a larger value in the 3rd column, for example, and return an array back.
I'd like something like this:

```
#col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
1         1       2       3       4
1         2       1       5       3
2         2       5       2       1
```

would return lines 1 and 3. 
Here's what I have so far: I defined an auxiliary function to detect the indexes of the duplicates (all second entries)

```
def list_duplicates(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [idx for idx,item in enumerate(seq) if item in seen or seen_add(item)]
```

and then try to use it to read the list (that I loaded from a file with np.genfromtxt naming each column)

```
def select_high(ndarray, dup_col, sel_col): #dup_col is the column where the duplicates are, sel_col is the column where we select the larger value
    result = []
    dup = list_duplicates(ndarray[dup_col])
    dupdup = [x-1 for x in dup]
    for i in range(len(ndarray[sel_col])):        
        if i in dup:
            mid = []
            maxi = max(ndarray[sel_col][i], ndarray[sel_col][i-1])
            maxi_index = np.where(ndarray[sel_col] == maxi)[0][0]
            for name in ndarray.dtype.names:
                mid.append(ndarray[name][maxi_index])
            result.append(mid)
        else:
            mid = []
            if i not in dupdup:
                for name in ndarray.dtype.names:
                    mid.append(ndarray[name][i])
            result.append(mid)

    return np.asarray(result)
```

but what's happening is that whenever there are duplicates I have to remove the `else` part or it gives me an error, and whenever there are no duplicates I have to put it back.
Any help is appreciated, sorry for the long post and I hope I made myself clear

Comment: What should a result be if in `col3` we will have these items: `1,2,3,2,1,4,5`? It should be all items which are greater than min element?

Comment: Can you add the error you are seeing to your question? It will make it much easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are lost in the details (and me too). Here is a version that does what you want, but is more simple:

```
m = [[1, 2, 1, 5, 3], [1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 2, 5, 2, 1]]
s = sorted(m,  key=lambda r:(r[0], -r[2]))
print(s) 
seen = set()
print( [r for r in s if r[0] not in seen and not seen.add(r[0])])
```

The first line defines `m` as the list of rows you get from the file.

The second line sorts those rows on the value in the first column (`r[0]`), then on the value in the third column, but from the larger to the smaller value (`-r[2]`):

```
s=[[1, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 1, 5, 3], [2, 2, 5, 2, 1]]
```

Now you need to skip the rows when you have seen the value in the first column at least once. We use a set `seen`to store the `r[0]` values we have already seen. If `r[0]` is not in `seen`, we should keep the row and put it in `seen`, in such a way that we discard the row the next time we see that `r[0]`. That's a little tricky:

```
if r[0] not in seen and not seen.add(r[0])
```

Note that `not seen.add(r[0])` is always true, because `seen.add` returns `None`. Thus:

- if `r[0]` is not in `seen`, we put `r[0]` in `seen` and keep the row
- if `r[0]` is in `seen`, we return false and discard the row.

You could express it like that too:

```
if not (r[0] in seen or seen.add(r[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to work and it's a lot simpler than I thought it would be. I was indeed needlessly complicating the problem. I guess I should maybe rephrase the question in pseudo code

Comment: @bernie You are using Python, a high level language: it requires some practice to avoid complicating your program with low level concerns. Having said that, my code implies a sort and may be slower that what you expected (*O(n lg n)* vs a possible *O(n)* time complexity).